# Prove that two circles are disjoint.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $C(O, r)$ and $C(O', r')$ be two distinct circles with $r \geq r'$. Suppose that $\overline{OO'} < r −r'$. Prove that $C(O, r)$ and $C(O', r')$ are disjoint.

I don't understand how this theorem works, so I definitely don't know how to go about proving it. Any tips or advice?

Comment: I think the best tip on how to get started is just draw some examples. Pick different values for $r$, $r'$ and the positions of $O$ an $O'$ and check, visually, by actually drawing the circles, that the theorem is true in each case. I predict that then it will suddenly look much more obvious and much less magical than it does now. After that the next step is to put into words why it is so obvious or what you are seeing and then the last step is to order these words into some logical 'proof-like' sequence

Comment: To be clear: much of mathematics looks magical when written down in one way and obvious when written down in another way and translating between the two is part of what math is and what makes it hard and creative. Just in this case the other way of writing it down (the way that makes clear what is going on) is no so much a question of writing but of drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction they are not disjoint, thus there is some point $P$ s.t.$P \in C(O, r) \cap C(O', r')$.
By the triangle inequality $\overline{OP} \leq \overline{OO'} + \overline{O'P}$ and since $P \in C(O, r)$ and $P \in C(O', r')$ then $r \leq \overline{OO'} + r'$, that is $\overline{OO'} \geq r - r'$, giving a contradiction to your hypothesis.

If you want an intuition of why this happens, observe that your hypothesis tells you that $r > \overline{OO'} + r'$, think of this geometrically (or draw a sketch of this starting with drawing $C(O', r')$, then picking $O$ as you like and finally picking $r$ so to make the inequality true), and you will notice that this means that $r$ is big enough to make $C(O', r')$ "fully contained" inside $C(O, r)$.

Hope this helps!